# Laravel: Check if all values exists in a relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a many to many relationship between `User` and `Role` models and want to check if a user has any role of a given list.

So I typed on model:

```
public function hasAnyRoles(array $roles) {
    return $this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->exists();
}
```

And on `UserController`:

```
// User has only "manager" role.
$user->hasAnyRoles(['admin', 'manager']) // true
```

The problem is that in some parts I need to verify if the user has all roles of the given list. For example:

```
// User has only "manager" role.
$user->hasRoles(['admin', 'manager']) // false
```

I wrote it in a "lazy" mode, that generates `n + 1` queries:

```
public function hasRolesLazy($roles) {
    return array_reduce($roles, function ($initial, $role) {
        return $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
    }, false);
}
```

How `hasRoles(array $roles)` method must be constructed to execute only one query in database? I'm a newbie in SQL so I can't figure out many solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function hasAnyRoles(array $roles) {
    return $this->whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($roles) {
         return $query->whereIn('name', $roles);
    })->isNotEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be, to load all of the roles for the user once using the relationship. When you load a relationship by calling it like a property, Laravel will cache it under the hood, so it doesn't repeat any queries. You can then simply use the loaded roles to implement your two methods:

```
public function hasAnyRoles(array $roles)
{
    // When you call $this->roles, the relationship is cached. Run through
    // each of the user's roles.
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        // If the user's role we're looking at is in the provided $roles
        // array, then the user has at least one of them. Return true.
        if (in_array($role->name, $roles) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // If we get here, the user does not have any of the required roles. 
    // Return false.
    return false;
}
```

and the second method:

```
public function hasRoles(array $roles)
{
    // Run through each of the roles provided, that the user MUST have
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        // Call the $this->roles relationship, which will return a collection
        // and be cached. Find the first role that has the name of the role
        // we're looking at.
        $found = $this->roles->first(function ($r) use ($role) {
            return $r->name == $role;
        });

        // If a role could not be found in the user's roles that matches the
        // one we're looking, then the user does not have the role, return 
        // false
        if (!$found) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we get here, the user has all of the roles provided to the method
    return true;
}
```

There are of course many different ways to implement these methods, particularly methods found in the `Collection` class will help you, but the point is that using `$this->roles` results in only a single query.